# How to enable PowerShell Interactive mode in Azure DevOps Azure Powershell Task?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm getting error in Azure DevOps Release pipeline -
Windows Powershell is in non Interactive mode. Read and Prompt Functionality is not available.

while running the command -

```
Start-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Trigger -ResourceGroupName "ADF" -DataFactoryName "WikiADF" -TriggerName "ScheduledTrigger"

Confirm
Are you sure you want to start trigger 'ScheduledTrigger' in data factory 'WikiADF'?
[Y] Yes  [N] No  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During the pipeline, you can't use the interactive mode in PowerShell.

Add the flag `-Force`, it's running the cmdlet without prompting for confirmation.

```
Start-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Trigger -ResourceGroupName "ADF" -DataFactoryName "WikiADF" -TriggerName "ScheduledTrigger" -Force
```

More info you can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.datafactoryv2/start-azurermdatafactoryv2trigger?view=azurermps-6.13.0#parameters).

Comment: Thanks Shayki. Where exactly I need to add this flag?

Comment: after `-TriggerName "ScheduledTrigger` - `-TriggerName "ScheduledTrigger -Force`

Comment: `-TriggerName "ScheduledTrigger" -Force` *

Answer (score 0):

No exactly what was asked - but in case you are looking for a way to see what is going on with you deployment task in a power-shell, you can use `-WhatIf`